# What is the meaning of "a|=b" in JS/TS if it's valid to begin with?

Tags: javascript, typescript, boolean, variable-types

When I see the expression

```
let a : number = 3;
a = a + 5;
```

I immediately refactor it to

```
let a : number = 3;
a += 5;
```

and in both cases, the result is *a===8* (I added the variable type for clarity). However, the boolean expression of the same pattern

```
let b : boolean = false;
b = b || true;
```

isn't equivalent to

```
let b : boolean = false;
b |= true;
```

as it produces a number. Now, the number correlates to *true* as it's a non-zero (and conversely, it corresponds to *false* in the opposite case as it returns zero). So there's a certain logic to that, of course.

It bugs me that I can't explain why it happens.

All the examples were executed in Chrome's console and I'm not entirely certain if the conversion to *number* from *boolean* occurs because of my operation or rendition in the browser or possibly something yet else.

Comment: Because `|` isn't the same as `||`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Bitwise_OR_assignment, not https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR

Comment: [Bitwise OR assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Bitwise_OR_assignment) - equivalent to `b = b | true` but you're supposed to use it with number: `a = 9; a|=7; a === 15`

Comment: Look closely: In `a |= b`, what is the operator? Hint: how many vertical bars are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` is a bitwise OR operation. `||` is the logical OR operation. `|=` is the compound bitwise OR assignment operator. There is no equivalent `||=` operator for `||` in JavaScript (though there's been [talk](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-logical-assignment) of adding it) and, so you can't do that refactoring with `||` (or `&&`), at least for now. (Well...you can if you use Babel, as there's [a plugin](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-logical-assignment-operators) for that proposal.)

Comment: Most bitwise operations can be used with booleans fine. I somewhat regularly use XOR with booleans although it's bitwise `Boolean(a ^ b)` will do the conversion, although `if (a ^ b)` is also fine, since it's going to be truthy/falsy anyway.

Comment: @VLAZ - Yes, it's just important to understand the differences: 1. The result is a number (which can be converted back to boolean). 2. Both operands are always evaluated. 3. The result isn't the same as either of the operands (whereas `||` takes the value of one of its operands). But yes, as you say, in many cases it's fine. (I think there may be a 4, but I'm still a bit sleepy... :-) )